# Group dataframe based on two datetime values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which shows start and end timestamps of a set of processes. I would like to count the number of processes active for any given minute. None of the pandas group/merge/join operations seems a good fit here. Here is a test dataset:

```
_range = pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-03-02', freq='1H')
start_ts = [random.choice(_range) for _ in range(48)]
end_ts = [r + datetime.timedelta(minutes=random.randint(1, 120)) for r in start_ts]

_processes = [random.choice(['Django', 'Flask', 'Pyramid', 'CherryPie']) for _ in start_ts]
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': start_ts, 'end_time': end_ts, 'process': _processes})
df.head()
           start_time            end_time    process
0 2020-03-01 00:00:00 2020-03-01 00:01:00     Django
1 2020-03-01 01:00:00 2020-03-01 01:04:00     Django
2 2020-03-01 02:00:00 2020-03-01 02:05:00      Flask
3 2020-03-01 03:00:00 2020-03-01 03:09:00      Flask
4 2020-03-01 04:00:00 2020-03-01 04:26:00  CherryPie
```

I have to count number of active processes, for each 1 minute interval between 2020/03/01 - 2020/03/02.
Here is one solution I can think of:

- Create a 1 minute interval dataframe between the said start/end date
- For each 1 minute interval, Iterate over the main dataframe and bucketise the record if the start_ts or end_ts falls in between a given minute.

Here is an sample solution:

```
df_stat = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-03-02', freq='1T'), columns=['count'])
for ts in df_stat.index:
    df_stat.loc[ts] = len(df[(df.start_time <= ts) & (df.end_time >= ts)])
df_stat.head()
                     count
2020-03-01 00:00:00      2
2020-03-01 00:01:00      2
2020-03-01 00:02:00      2
2020-03-01 00:03:00      2
2020-03-01 00:04:00      2
```

This doesn't look like an elegant solution. When the observation window is large, iteration can take longer. Are there any native pandas operator available that we can use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about this some more, I came up with a pandas way, which I hope is fast enough for your data. The key idea is that we can uncouple the start and end times, because it doesn't matter which start time belongs to which end time. All that matters is how many processes have started and how many have ended at any given moment. So if we code starts as 1 and ends as -1, the number of running processes is the cumulative sum over those.

```py
# create a dataframe with a '1'-column for starting processes
# and a '-1'-column for ending processes
df_times = df.drop('process', axis=1)
df_times.columns = [1, -1]

# melt the two columns into one (the increment column)
df_long = pd.melt(df_times, var_name='inc', value_name='time')

# group by time and sum the increments if events coincide
df_stat = df_long.groupby('time').sum()

# now the count of running processes is the cumulative sum of increments
df_stat['count'] = df_stat.inc.cumsum()
df_stat.drop('inc', axis=1, inplace=True)

# upsample to minutely frequency
df_stat = df_stat.resample('1T').ffill()
```

Comment: Looks like a bit complicated for a fairly simple task, but this worked (at least for the sample dataset I had), and the performance matched my expectation !

Answer (score 0):

It does feel appropriate to create a one-minute interval DataFrame (or a Series). However, depending on the input, it could be faster (compared to your solution) to iterate over the original DataFrame and increment the counts accordingly:

```py
df_stat = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2020-03-01', end='2020-03-02', freq='1T'), 
                       columns=['count'])
df_stat.fillna(0, inplace=True)

for i in df.index:
    df_stat.loc[df.start_time.loc[i]:df.end_time.loc[i]] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Arne. It's definitely an improvement over my original proposal, still not fast enough to iterate through 50k+ records.